# what is the attribute that handles timeout

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to install MySQL through VM Extension with JSON Template but it is throwing an error like 
"Provisioning of VM extension InstallMySql has timed out. Extension has taken too long to complete. This extension did not report a message".

Can anyone help how to handle timeouts and what is the attribute that handles timeout?

Answer (score 0):

This is something you cannot control, its set to 90 minutes. Take a look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#tips-and-tricks). I'm assuming you are using script extension.

Comment: Yes i am using script extension. i am runnig my shell script file through extension

Comment: nothing you can do in this case. use a golden image. or make your script run faster (use bigger VM sku\premium disks)